# Matplotlib heatmap for multiple timeseries to show distribution over time

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

I have n_series recordings with the same frames 0, 1, 2, 3,... and would like to make a 2D contour out of it.

I've found that I can very easily do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

series_len = 1000
n_series = 10

y = np.random.normal(0, 0.15, series_len * n_series)
x = np.tile(np.arange(0, series_len, 1), n_series)

heatmap, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=20)

plt.contourf(heatmap.T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But since this just gives a 20x20 histogram, I have no idea how my intensities are distributed in the outputted plot (e.g. roughly zero-centered), nor how to fix the ticks.

What I'd like is this ('shopped):
[image]

Comment: I am not sure, if that is what you want, but maybe try `bins=200`?

Comment: What should your x ticks look like?

Comment: *I have no idea how my intensities are distributed*: how would you want to see the intensity distribution?

Comment: Edited main post. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `set_xticklabels`:

```
series_len = 1000
n_series = 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
np.random.seed(1)
y = np.random.normal(0, 0.15, series_len * n_series)
x = np.tile(np.arange(0, series_len, 1), n_series)

heatmap, xs, ys = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.contourf(heatmap.T)

# the actual x-axis and y-axis are from 0 to 19
# we want to put 11 ticks on the axis
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,19,11))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(0,1001,100))

ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,19,11))
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:.3f}'.format(y) for y in ys[::2]])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Looks great! But umm... the xticks aren't lining up correctly, which means that the yticks probably aren't either.

Comment: True, the problem is your `heatmap` is `20x20` so by default `ax` has `20` ticks on each axis, while `xs` has 21 elements, fixing

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, did you want something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

series_len = 1000
n_series = 10

y = np.random.normal(0, 0.15, series_len * n_series)
x = np.tile(np.arange(0, series_len, 1), n_series)

heatmap, xlabels, ylabels = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=20)

plt.contourf(xlabels[:-1], ylabels[:-1], heatmap.T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Almost, and a very easy solution indeed. However, the ticks aren't correctly lined up, as you'll see if you increase `n_series`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found an answer myself which makes the process *much* simpler than it appears to be. Simply resize the heatmap by 1 in both directions using `skimage` will make everything follow along nicely.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform

series_len = 1000
n_series = 10
bins = 20
y = np.random.normal(0, 0.15, series_len * n_series)
x = np.tile(np.arange(0, series_len, 1), n_series)

heatmap, xlabels, ylabels = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
heatmap = skimage.transform.resize(heatmap, output_shape = (bins+1, bins+1), mode = "symmetric")

plt.contourf(xlabels, ylabels, heatmap.T)
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]